# LISP help! Candy machine dispenser

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Hey guys I'm new here and I was wondering if you guys can give me any help. I'm creating a candy machine that dispense colors randomly.I've ran this code and it goes on for 7 times for (get-candy *gummy-bear*) but it should go for 4 times till nil.

So heres my code:

```
 ;;; function get-candy
(defun get-candy (machine)
  (funcall machine))

;;; variable colors
(defvar *colors* '(red blue green brown yellow purple))

;;; function generate-candy-supply
(defun generate-candy-supply (num)
 (if (= 0 num)
    (cons (nth (+ 1 (random (- (length *colors*) 1))) *colors*) *colors* )
    (generate-candy-supply (- num 1))))


;;; function candy-machine
(defun candy-machine (candy)
  (function
    (lambda ()
      (prog1 (car candy)
        (setq candy (cdr candy))))))


;;; variable gummy-bear
(defvar *gummy-bear*
  (candy-machine (generate-candy-supply 4)))

;;; variable easter-egg
(defvar *easter-egg*
  (candy-machine (generate-candy-supply 6)))
```

And the sample run should look like this:

```
[1]> (load 'candy.lisp)
;; Loading file candy.lisp ...
;; Loaded file candy.lisp
T
[2]> (get-candy *gummy-bear*)
BLUE
[3]> (get-candy *gummy-bear*)
BROWN
[4]> (get-candy *gummy-bear*)
YELLOW
[5]> (get-candy *gummy-bear*)
YELLOW
[6]> (get-candy *gummy-bear*)
NIL
[7]> (get-candy *easter-egg*)
BLUE
[8]> (get-candy *easter-egg*)
BROWN
[9]> (get-candy *easter-egg*)
GREEN
[10]> (get-candy *easter-egg*)
BROWN
[11]> (get-candy *easter-egg*)
YELLOW
[12]> (get-candy *easter-egg*)
BLUE
[13]> (get-candy *easter-egg*)
NIL
```

Comment: This looks *very much* like [Lisp randomize and using two functions to pull from list into another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27098434/1281433) from a few weeks ago, where the asker said,  "I am trying to create a candy machine that dispense colors randomly."  It's not a problem to ask about homework assignments, but it's usually a good idea to make that clear, and quite possibly to provide a reference to the assignment (since copying any code from it would otherwise be plagiarism).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the function `generate-candy-supply`. It has two branches depending on `num`. If it is not `0` you recurse with `(1- num)` and do nothing else. When `num` is `0` you return a list starting with a random element of `*colors*` followed by the elements of `*colors*`. This will always yield a list with exactly 7 elements.

I'll leave it at this for now, so you can have a try at figuring a solution out. Feel free to ask further questions in the comments.